# Include Youtube Video in .Rpres Presentation

Tags: r, html, rstudio, rpres

How would I embed the following Youtube Video in my RStudio .Rpres presentation?

http://www.youtube.com/embed/TR2bHSJ_eck?feature=player_detailpage

I could not find any info in the link below:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486468-Authoring-R-Presentations

Answer (score 3):

You can include HTML code in rpresentation. So this:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TR2bHSJ_eck"></iframe>
```

should work when viewing your presentation in your browser

You can also use embed:

```
<embed width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TR2bHSJ_eck">
```